# Is the following function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be an strictly increasing map and $f(\mathbb R)$ is closed in $\mathbb R$. Is $f$ continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, f is continuous.
f(R) is closed, thus lim(x->x_0 from left)f(x)=A belongs to f(R), but as f is strictly increasing, you can prove that A must equals f(x_0). In the same manner, you can prove that lim(x->x_0 from right)f(x)=f(x_0). The argument above proves the conclusion.